# Is it required to remove pyenv init invocations when uninstalling pyenv?

Tags: macos, pyenv

I recently installed pyenv on my Mac using Homebrew. I installed it by entering the command `brew install pyenv` in the terminal, that's it. I didn't do any other required steps like executing `echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile` in the terminal or anything else.

Anyways, I now uninstalled pyenv using the `rm -rf $(pyenv root)` command, and then the `brew uninstall pyenv` command in the terminal since I didn't use pyenv at all.

My question comes down to, was I supposed to remove the pyenv init invocations from my shell startup configuration before uninstalling pyenv using the `rm -rf $(pyenv root)` command? Then follow it by the `brew uninstall pyenv` command?

I didn't think I would have to do that step when uninstalling pyenv because, once again, I didn't do any other required steps for installing pyenv, other than just executing the `brew install pyenv` command in the terminal.

I am using zsh (if that matters to anyone). If I do have to reinstall pyenv and remove the pyenv init invocations from my shell startup configuration + the other steps used for uninstalling it, then please tell me how to do that task. If I don't have to remove the pyenv init invocations from my shell startup configuration, then ok, that's good.

Comment: Seems pretty similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68788732/2745495

Comment: ya it is, yet that question along with mine is still not answered... :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please use better structure of paragraphs in your future questions to make it look nice to read by others who want to help you. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyenv` doesn't write the init script into your zsh init files automatically.

So, if haven't touched `.zshrc`, `.zprofile` file after installing `pyenv`, you don't have to manually remove these `pyenv` init script.

And your uninstallation steps are correct:

- `rm -rf "$(pyenv root)"` removes the folder where compiled python, virtualenv are stored.
- `brew uninstall pyenv` removes the package itself.